# PayPal API With ActiveMerchant (Legacy Code)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I've inherited some legacy Rails code (2.1.3) and there appears to be a `public_cert` as well as a `signature`. I thought PayPal used one or the other, but my configuration seems to have both:

```
config.app_config.pay_pal.merge!(
  :password=>"WHATEVER",
  :public_key=>"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIICmTCCAgKgAwIBAgIDEcmhMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGZMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV\nUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTERMA8GA1UEBxMIU2FuIEpvc2UxFTATBgNV\nBAoTCHANGEDSTUFFqe0RzCDhQmVhgtNWZxeqzjVbVrCx80jF1\nWi/+ksJQLPViFj9+F4WS5i4MjMeCIwIDAQABow0wCzAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMA0GCSqG\nSIb3DQEBBQUAA4GBAMwavx4Eh2JCOCOc/WvL7zdRL07So48mQ9aJr4Bxdgib+/z2\nkqX0ZPJv9T6NQ1h9lcwohIuaJMXtLAysJMjvKcvPdzcHqB6Xv+OGpi2REJjUdB39\n9amutkxQVhKBfK3hCP4+8UlM1yzxejyK8SVWSJCbc5zvJFoLV4SZcbNevtw9\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
  :business=>"me@site.com",
  :business_id=>"4WSDFSFSDF",
  :login=>"me_api1.site.com",
  :cert_id=>"AAAA",
  :private_key=>"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICXAIBAAKBgQDm5fXKcp6ht6+Be4Y7VOaNvEPZwVqRt0CHANGEDMORESTUFFKTF7Mozcg12qiq1VDqFYwQF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\n1RskSziPqfQyA2QDFfSPkmycgxPlZvP0G8fwuBs6sjI=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  :signature=>"AwhNvKUCHANGEDSTUFF9xveB4"
)
```

I'm using `PayPal Payments Standard` I believe with Rails `ActiveMerchant`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal only allows you to use one or the other.  It may have been that the previous person generated the cert or signature and added it to the code, only to switch over to the other method at a later date and never removed it from the code.  If it's currently working and processing payments on the PayPal account, you could log into the PayPal account and see which one is currently active on the account.  You are only going to see one or the other.  Which ever one you are seeing, means the other one would not be being used.  If it's not showing, it would not be valid anymore.

Another option, would be you could walk thru the code and see where the API call is being made, and check which one it is sending across to PayPal.